# Can iOS app subscription options be hidden from users?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, app-store-connect

My iOS app currently offers an auto-renewable subscription **A**. I want to add a second subscription option **B** with a discounted rate. Option **B** shall only be available for users who bought a certain upgrade **X** via in-app purchase in the past (that in-app purchase is not offered for sale anymore).

How can I prevent that users subscribe to **A** and then switch to **B** in the System Settings? Users who didn't purchase **X** shouldn't even know that **B** exists.

As far as I understand [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/) and [App Store Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev75708c031), users can upgrade/downgrade/crossgrade between subscriptions in the same subscription group. I assume that by adding the subscriptions to two different subscription groups, switching between **A** and **B** is not possible, but I couldn't find a definitive answer on this.

If a user starts any subscription, will they automatically see all subscription groups in the System Settings, or just the group with an active subscription?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If a user starts any subscription, will they automatically see all subscription groups in the System Settings, or just the group with an active subscription?

**Users can never see the products from another subscription group.** Only if **A** and **B** are in the same subscription group, the user will be able to change the plan using System Settings.

To determine the eligibility of the user to buy **B**, you could check the receipt's `latest_receipt_info` property. If a purchase record of **X** is present, offer the user to subscribe to **B**, otherwise, offer **A**.